# Timeout error occurs when calling detectedActivity of awareness API on os13

Tags: android, timeout, android-13, google-awareness

com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:19.0.1
Android OS 10,13

Timeout error in os13 when calling detectedActivity() of awareness API.

There is no problem on os9, but it is happening on os13.

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15:
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zap.onComplete(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.contextmanager.zzch.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness@@18.0.2:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.contextmanager.zzcp.zzi(com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness@@18.0.2:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.contextmanager.zzcq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness@@18.0.2:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.contextmanager.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness@@18.0.2:3)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1316)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)
```

Has anyone solved this problem?

There was nothing I could try...